# Prometheus: Changing unit on Y axis

Tags: prometheus, grafana, k6

here is my prometheus yml:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 3s # Set the scrape interval to every 3 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 5s # Evaluate rules every 5 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
          # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: "prometheus"

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]
```

Prometheus is launched like:

```
prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --web.enable-remote-write-receiver --enable-feature=native-histograms
```

K6 load test:

```
k6 run -o experimental-prometheus-rw  dist/get-all-node-requests-test.js
```

I see metrics appear in Prometheus - but k6 generates metrics in ms and I would like to have ms in Prometheus (Y axis). Would you please advise how I can change it

[image]

Comment: On one hand Prometheus' web console is rather simplistic, and you can't configure anything outside of controls shown on top: range, end time, etc. Grafana is recommended as a tool for visualisation of data from Prometheus.

Comment: On the other hand, I'm not entirely sure Prometheus preserves milliseconds of scrape time, and thus not sire if it's possible to do in any tool.